# Why OS Module in Python giving output of Epoche Time standard only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-requests, operating-system

Why Epoche Time standard in again and again appearing in my output. I expected my Epoche Time standard output in stat.ST_ATIME but it is appreaing in both of my outputs.

Input:

```
import os
import datetime
import stat

os.stat("abc.txt")

print("File size in byte is:",stat.ST_SIZE)
print("File last modified is:",datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stat.ST_MTIME))
print("File last accessed is:",datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stat.ST_ATIME))
```

Output:

```
File size in byte is: 6    
File last modified is: 1970-01-01 05:00:08
File last accessed is: 1970-01-01 05:00:07
```

Expected:

```
File size in byte is: 6
File last modified is: 2021-08-21 05:00:08
File last accessed is: 1970-01-01 05:00:07
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stat.ST_MTIME` is not the time. It's a *fixed programming constant*. It's the integer value `8`:

```
>>> import stat
>>> stat.ST_MTIME
8
```

`os.stat()` returns the structure you want to look at, see the [`os.stat_result` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result). Your code ignored the returned object, you want to store it in a variable then use the attributes of that variable:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

stat_result = os.stat("abc.txt")

print("File size in byte is:", stat_result.st_size)
print("File last modified is:", datetime.fromtimestamp(stat_result.st_mtime))
print("File last accessed is:", datetime.fromtimestamp(stat_result.st_mtime))
```

The [`stat.ST_*` constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html) are indexes into the named tuple that `os.stat()` returns, but you don't need them here as the named tuple also supports named attributes.

You should prefer to use the named attributes however, as you may get *more detailed values*; the `stat_result.st_mtime` attribute gives you the value of `stat_result.st_mtime_ns` value dividid by 1 billion, wheras `stat_result[8]` or `stat_result[stat.ST_MTIME]` gives you the value rounded to whole seconds:

```
>>> open("abc.txt", "w").write("Some example text into the file\n")
32
>>> stat_result = os.stat("abc.txt")
>>> stat_result.st_mtime
1629566790.0892947
>>> stat_result.st_mtime_ns
1629566790089294590
>>> stat_result.st_mtime_ns / (10 ** 9)
1629566790.0892947
>>> stat_result[stat.ST_MTIME]
1629566790
```

Using indexing gives you integers for backwards compatibility with older code.